# Interface Design: Specific vs General parameter (A Minimal design vs anticipated use variation)

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, interfaces, code-reviews, clean-code

### Code

```cs
public interface IVehicle {
   string VehicleMake { get; }
   int MonthsSincePurchase { get; }
   bool IsApprovedUsed { get; }
   ...
}

public class WarrantyPopUpHandler {
   virtual bool ShouldShowPopup(IVehicle vehicle /* What should I pass in?*/) {
      return false; 
   }
}

public class VolvoWarrantyPopupHandler : WarrantyPopUpHandler {
   override bool ShouldShowPopup(IVehicle vehicle) {
      return vehicle.MonthsSincePurchase < 12;
   }
}

public class BMWWarrantyPopupHandler : WarrantyPopUpHandler {
   override bool ShouldShowPopup(IVehicle vehicle) {
      return vehicle.MonthsSincePurchase < 12;
   }
}
```

### Explanation

Looking at the above pseudo-code there is a `IVehicle` type that exposes lots of properties of a vehicle. Now some customers want to show a popup for some vehicles and the programmer starts designing a `WarrantyPopupHandler`. Currently Volvo and BMW want the popup, and they both want it based on the vehicles age. The programmer implements the two derived classes as shown.

What should the `ShouldShowPopup()` method take as parameter. The only thing it needs from the current use cases is the `int MonthsSincePurchase`. Is it at present premature to supply the entire IVehicle, should it only take an `int`?

But there is a very good chance that during the demo another customer, say Ford, for example, will catch the idea and will want the same popup but maybe only for ApprovedUsed (`IsApprovedUsed`) vehicles in the future. The programmer knows this by experience.

Also there will be lots of other code written that will rely on calling `WarrantyPopUpHandler::ShouldShowPopup`.

Also note that the base class version ignores the incoming parameter and returns false all the time, so here it seems wasteful to supply a parameter at all.

### Bonus question

Does the answer change if IVehicle is part of a larger interface.

```cs
interface VehicleInvoice
{
    IVehicle Vehicle { get; }
    ICustomer Customer { get; }
    ...
}
```

Should the programmer have rather supplied `VehicleInvoice` to `ShouldShowPopup` given that customer data *may* (a rare case by experience) also factor in the decision to show a popup in the future?

### See Also

The question is a variation of my earlier question: [Minimal design vs anticipated use](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/299489/minimal-design-vs-anticipated-use). 
How should the answers there influence the design choice here?

### Polite Note

I would like answers to try and focus on or discuss what design principles apply here and not treat this as a refactoring exercise that avoids the question being asked. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interface Implementation: A parameter I don't need](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/299891/interface-implementation-a-parameter-i-dont-need)

Comment: @WindRaven I have asked both questions, I don't think they are duplicates. This is about passing a more generic variant of a parameter, while the other is about differing use of an existing interface. They are close but I do not think they are duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making the parameter an `IVehicle` is better. You're essentially using your `WarrantyPopupHandler` hierarchy to add a method with a default implementation to `IVehicle`. Making the parameter an `int` wouldn't make sense because `ShouldShowPopup` is assuming a certain "meaning" for the `int` (ie. that the `int` holds `IVehicle.MonthsSincePurchase`). Since it would be a logic error to call `ShouldShowPopup` with an `int` that means something else, the parameter might as well be an `IVehicle`. Using an `IVehicle` also improves encapsulation since the caller of `ShouldShowPopup` doesn't have to examine the internal structure of `IVehicle`.

As for the `VehicleInvoice` interface, that comes down to domain knowledge. It seems to me that a warranty is associated with a particular *transaction*, which seems to be what `VehicleInvoice` represents. So in the particular case of your "bonus" question, I'd be inclined to make it `ShouldShowPopup(VehicleInvoice)`. Obviously if you carry this thinking too far you end up with global variables, so you have to use your best judgment.

Comment: I agree, but I am unable to reconcile this with the minimal design folks who say pass in no more then you absolutely need.

Comment: So what is stopping you from creating a IWarrantyPopup interface that contains only the information you need?

Comment: @Dunk Nothing. Can you elaborate your solution as an answer please.